# Why does a light switch that is switched off show 50 volts between hot and neutral?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, old-work

It's a two-wire light fixture without ground. When the switch is on I measure 120 volts between the hot and neutral in the ceiling fixture. If I switch it off I measure 50 volts. Why?

Comment: What are you using to measure this voltage?

Comment: Sounds like phantom voltage to me, we have a couple of thousand questions on that.

Comment: I am measuring in a ceiling fixture. On the actual wires.

Comment: @brentonstrine -- no, I'm asking about the meter you're using to make that voltage measurement

Comment: Oh! Sorry. A multimeter. What else can you use to measure voltage?

Comment: @brentonstrine -- does your multimeter have a Low-Z function on it?

Comment: I'll have to check. Looks like that function will help eliminate phantom voltage, which it seems is what I'm experiencing.